# How to add text forward instead of backwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to align a collection of rows with a title in the front of each row. But the position of the rows will change according to the length of the title. So I figure if I can increase the length of the text forward instead of backwards, I may be able to solve this problem. But I don't know how to do it. Any help is appreciated!

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class="title">1</span>
  <a href="#" class="cells">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">three</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">four</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">five</a>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="title">100</span>
  <a href="#" class="cells">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">three</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">four</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">five</a>
</div>
```

**What I hope it to look like regardless of the length of the title:**
[image]

**What it looks like now:**
[image]

Here's a [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5L31q9ko/1/).

Comment: could 100 be 1000? or any random number?

Comment: @Stephen any random number or string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to make the divs display as table rows and the spans and links as cells:

```
.title, .cells {
  display: table-cell;
}
div {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```css
.cells {
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.title {
  min-width: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.title,
.cells {
  display: table-cell;
}

div {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="title">1</span>
  <a href="#" class="cells">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">three</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">four</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">five</a>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="title">100</span>
  <a href="#" class="cells">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">three</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">four</a>
  <a href="#" class="cells">five</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the simplest and also responsive suggestion. I apply your advice with react-material-layout in my project and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td><a href="">cell1</a></td>
    <td><a href="">cell2</a></td>
    <td><a href="">cell3</a></td>
    <td><a href="">cell4</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="">cell5</a></td>
    <td><a href="">cell6</a></td>
    <td><a href="">cell7</a></td>
    <td><a href="">cell8</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```